# PHP/MySql - Creating navigation buttons

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm totally stuck! I need to create navigation buttons in order to go through records that match a specific Id. So far I have only been able to retrieve 1 record (the first one). I am using the following code to do so:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.requester_name, t1.requester_email, t1.client_name, t1.client_country, t1.machine_quantity, t1.severity, t1.sales_connect, t1.request_status, t2.serial_type, t2.serial_model, t2.serial_number, t2.machine_status, t2.machine_config, t2.brand, t2.tier, t2.request_id
FROM requests t1
LEFT JOIN serialnumbers t2
ON t1.request_id = t2.request_id
WHERE t1.request_id = {$id} ";

$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
```

The records are coming from 2 distinct tables and while I am having no trouble with the Request Table (Always one row), I cannot manage to figure out how to get every row in the Serial Numbers table (one to many relationship).

I am using a html form to display these values... Here is a sample of how I am doing so:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['serial_type']; ?>" id="machineType" name="machineType[]" />
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this objective?

Answer (score 1):

you are going to want to make your $row = mysql_fetch_assoc a while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$row['serial-type']." id="machineType" name="machineType[]" />';
}
```

something along those lines.